# How to install python modules in a Azure function app

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-blob-storage

I need help debugging this or working out how to run this code in Azure functions.
it's currently failing and I'm unsure on pythons modules. Assumed it trying to install but is failing at the first step

my error

> Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 458, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 701, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/httptrigger-pmaas-data-transformation/**init**.py", line 30, in main from .run_transformation import run File "/home/site/wwwroot/httptrigger-pmaas-data-

My __Init.py

```
import azure.functions as func 
import logging
import os
from subprocess import check_call
try:
    check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy==1.21.4'])
    check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pandas==1.2.4'])
    check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'azure-storage-blob==12.8.0'])
    check_call(["python3", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'openpyxl==3.0.10'])
    from .run_transformation import run
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
except:
    pass  def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy==1.21.4'])
        check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pandas==1.2.4'])
        check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'azure-storage-blob==12.8.0'])
        check_call(["python3", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'openpyxl==3.0.10'])
        from .run_transformation import run
        from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    except:
        check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy==1.21.4'])
        check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pandas==1.2.4'])
        check_call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'azure-storage-blob==12.8.0'])
        check_call(["python3", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'openpyxl==3.0.10'])
        from .run_transformation import run
        from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    logging.info('Starting Data Transformation')
    connectionString = os.environ['SA_CONNECTION_STRING']
    exceptions = run(connectionString)     if len(exceptions) > 0:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Failed! :: One more files were not processed. List of exceptions. {exceptions}",
            status_code=200
        )
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "Success! :: Data Transfomration is completed. Check log for more details and troubleshooting",
            status_code=200
    )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The modules you would like to install should be included in the `requirements.txt` file. The requirements.txt *contains the list of Python packages the system installs when publishing to Azure.* Assuming that you are using the v1 programming model, you can find [more details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#folder-structure).

In your case the `requirements.txt` file would contain the corresponding modules...

```
numpy==1.21.4
pandas==1.2.4
azure-storage-blob==12.8.0
openpyxl==3.0.10
```

... which will then be installed during publishing so that you import them into your code as usual.

Comment: Do I need to reference this before the _init.py 
Sorry I inherited this code so trying to understand the chain of things especially in the function app on azure as it puts all the scripts alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @holger for pointing in the right direction. After reproducing from my end, I faced the same issue but after adding the modules in requirements.txt file I could able to solve this. I have achieved your requirement using

```
Popen(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=open('requirements.txt', 'w'))
```

Below is the complete code that worked for me.

```
import azure.functions as func 
import logging
import os
from subprocess import check_call, Popen

try:
    check_call(['pip', 'install', 'numpy==1.21.4'])
    check_call(['pip', 'install', 'pandas==1.2.4'])
    check_call(['pip', 'install', 'azure-storage-blob==12.8.0'])
    check_call(['pip', 'install', 'openpyxl==3.0.10'])
    from .run_transformation import run
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    
except:
    def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        try:
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'numpy==1.21.4'])
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'pandas==1.2.4'])
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'azure-storage-blob==12.8.0'])
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'openpyxl==3.0.10'])
            from .run_transformation import run
            from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
        except:
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'numpy==1.21.4'])
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'pandas==1.2.4'])
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'azure-storage-blob==12.8.0'])
            check_call(['pip', 'install', 'openpyxl==3.0.10'])
            Popen(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=open('requirements.txt', 'w'))
            
            from .run_transformation import run
            from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
            
            logging.info('Starting Data Transformation')
            connectionString = os.environ['SA_CONNECTION_STRING']
            exceptions = run(connectionString) 
                
            if len(exceptions) > 0:
                return func.HttpResponse(
            "Failed! :: One more files were not processed. List of exceptions. {exceptions}",
            status_code=200
            )
                
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Success! :: Data Transfomration is completed. Check log for more details and troubleshooting",
            status_code=200
        )
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swethas answer is a way if you execute it locally

if you publish the code to be executed in the azure environment there is an easier way

once you execute the publish command:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV1zj.png) e.g.

```
func azure functionapp publish *functionappname* --build-remote
```

all the listed dependencies in your requirements.txt will be installed in azure

So you dont need to handle it in your code

Important is the location of the requirements.txt in the root:
[dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV1zj.png)

Comment: I'm doing exactly this, and the functionapp gets published, but the requirements are not installed. I have `requirements.txt` in the right spot (in the root, but outside of the function directories themselves). Beating my head against the wall for a long time now.